# Кидает android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: java, android

Пишу прогу для Android но при переходе на активити `Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OtzivyActivity.class)` Кидает ошибку `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`.
Вот весь код

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    ListView lv;

    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

    // url получения списка всех продуктов
    private static String url_all_products = "http://127.0.0.1/get_all_otzivy.php";


    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_OTZIV = "otziv";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";


    JSONArray products = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();



                new LoadAllProducts().execute();




        // *получаем ListView
         lv = getListView();

        // В этом месте происходит ошибка
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {



                String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                        .toString();


                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OtzivyActivity.class);

                in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);


                startActivityForResult(in, 100);

            }
        });

    }




    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == 100) {

            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Фоновый Async Task для загрузки всех запросов по HTTP 
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Перед началом фонового потока Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Загрузка базы. Подождите...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Получаем все запросы из url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Будет хранить параметры
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // получаем JSON строк с URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

            Log.d("Все отзывы: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Получаем SUCCESS тег для проверки статуса ответа сервера
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {

                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_OTZIV);

                    // перебор 
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Сохраняем каждый json елемент в переменную
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                        // Создаем новый HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // добавляем каждый елемент в HashMap ключ => значение
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                        // добавляем HashList в ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * После завершения фоновой задачи закрываем прогрес диалог
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // закрываем прогресс диалог 
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // обновляем UI форму в фоновом потоке
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Обновляем распарсенные JSON данные в ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            MainActivity.this, productsList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                            TAG_NAME},
                            new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                    // обновляем listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }
```

Comment: Вы так торопились, что даже не додумались скрыть хотя бы адрес на `php` скрипт?

Comment: Попробуйте просто пока что убрать `startActivityForResult` и пока просто перейдите на другую активность через `startActivity`. У меня подозрения на код внутри `onActivityResult`. Мне кажется, что эти три строки - плохой код.. Вы что таким образом решили перезапустить активность?

Comment: Покажите код класса `OtzivyActivity` и полный стек-трейс.

Comment: Кстати, метод `onPostExecute(...)` выполняется в UI-потоке, поэтому Ваша конструкция с `runOnUiThread(...)` там не нужна.

Comment: Попробуйте перенести инициализацию парсера прямо в метод `doInBackGround()`. Т.е. вот это `JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();`

Comment: Я пробовал менять на startActivity, делал другую Активити, в OtzivyActivity нет ничего, ошибка выходит еще до нее.

Comment: Не помог ни один вариант

Comment: Необходимо увидеть всю ошибку, чтобы понять на что он ругается

Comment: Заработало, Спасибо  post_zeew, точно лишнее runOnUiThread(...) было.